# MPMoviePlayerController: How can I make my video loop?

Tags: cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

Thank you in advance for any help, I am a newbie and would appreciate any help here..
I have this code to play a movie and it works great.  Can somebody PLEASE tell me how to make this movie loop and replay from the beginning non stop ( any code would help).   Also I would like to know how to play 2 movies, one after the other, preferably with a fade or smooth transition.  Thank you for any help

```
#import "MyAppViewController.h"

@implementation MyAppViewController

-(IBAction)button:(id)sender{
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
       pathForResource:@"mymovie" ofType:@"mp4"];

 player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
     initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

 [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];

}
```

Comment: Please format your code next time.

Answer (score 23):

Set the [`repeatMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMovieRepeatMode) property of your `MPMoviePlayerController` to `MPMovieRepeatModeOne`

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
          initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
player.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
```

Comment: I did and now I get a line error on:  player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
>>>>Request for member 'repeatMode' is something not a structure or union-  <<<<  I think we're close...can you help ?

Comment: Awesome, Works great.   Ok one more question.  I need to be able to add a timer to my movie; ie..make it stop after a set time.  I would like to use a slider for that, any ideas how to add that ?

Comment: @JacobRelkin hello, thanks for answer how can I make looping without 0.01 sec delay after player start to play again?

Comment: For SWIFT, use moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One

Answer (score 20):

`MPMovieRepeatModeOne` is nice but it doesn't loop the video very smoothly. Try this below (copied from another post) :

(I just got this working on my iPad 3 running iOS 5.1.1, base SDK iOS 5.1.)

When setting up the movie player, set the repeat mode to `MPMovieRepeatModeNone` then add the notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidFinish:)
            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                            object:self.moviePlayer];
```

Then set up your selector to filter when the movie finishes playing:

```
- (void)moviePlayerDidFinish:(NSNotification *)note
{
    if (note.object == self.moviePlayer) {
        NSInteger reason = [[note.userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] integerValue];
        if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded)
        {
            [self.moviePlayer play];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The weird thing for me was that this worked great in the simulator, but trying it on an actual phone it sometimes looped and sometimes got stuck at the end. I suspected a racing condition (where play is called when actually the movie is not completely finished yet). When I added an NSTimer to delay the calling of the play method, indeed it looped (but with a hickup at the end), which is not optimal. Maybe it's because of the .mp4 file's codec?

Comment: It is good practice to use: [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay]; This helps with optimizing the video and removing any unwanted rendering issues.

Comment: No longer works with iOS8+. The gap is just as long as setting the repeatMode to .One

Answer (score 1):

For the timer you can create an Int variable that has the value of your slider and then use a performSelector afterDelay:

```
int delayInt = 8; // Substitute the 8 for the value of your slider
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:delayInt];
```

And then in your "myMethod"

```
-(void) myMethod{
//the code to stop your player and remove view controller
}
```