# repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne loops video in simulator but not in iPhone. Known issue?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, video, ios-simulator

I'm quite new to iOS development so not knowing if this is a known problem or not, or why I am seeing this. I have a screen in my app that plays a video over and over again. On the previous screen the user selects which video by pressing different buttons which sets the videoURL property of the view controller that handles the screen that plays the video. And this is how the viewDidLoad method looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: self.videoURL];
    player.repeatMode=MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    player.controlStyle =MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player.view setFrame: self.videoView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
    [self.videoView addSubview: player.view];
    [player play];
}
```

This works great in the simulator. The video loops as expected. But once I deploy it on some hardware it will not loop, just play once. I have tried it on two different iPhone 4, one with iOS 6.1.3 and one with iOS 7.0.3.

Any ideas why I see this behaviour?

**EDIT:**
I noticed that this code works as expected on iPhone5 hardware but not on iPhone4 hardware. Has not been able to test on iPhone4S or any of the new 5s or 5c.

Answer (score 0):

try this one, May be help you.

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
          initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
player.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
```

or see below link

[MPMoviePlayerController: How can I make my video loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580712/mpmovieplayercontroller-how-can-i-make-my-video-loop)

Comment: Thanks, tried the first but does not help. I noticed that my original code works on iPhone5 hardware but not on iPhone4 hardware. Has not been able to test on iPhone4S or any of the new 5s or 5c.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this is only occurring on older phones. I've had the same problem on iPhone 4, where as 5 and 5S seem to repeat fine. I heard mention that it might be a memory issue (the playback doesn't work because there is no memory), but on the iPhone4 I have there is more than enough.

Also tried setting the values through their accessor methods rather than accessing them directly with no luck.

It might be a hardware issue, as the iPhone 4 is running the same OS version as the iPhone 5's.